# How to claim disk space by removing all the files and hard links?

Tags: linux, hard-link

I've been trying for hours to figure this out but cant seems to do it

My question Is I have a file name easy and there's 4 different sub directories in it 
[image]

now what I have to do is delete everything under foo (including hard links) and reclaim all the diskspace of foo.

I tried removing all the file by typing.

> rm foo/*

but it does not remove the hard links that are in the other sub directories.

Then I tried to see if the Matching inodes

> find foo -type f -ls | sort

and this is what I got with this command

[image]

this command doesn't show the others sub directories only foo/

can someone please help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: [PSA: Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Comment: may be I didn't get your question right, but if you're trying to remove everything under foo, cant you just  do -- rm -fr foo/* ?

Comment: but it doesn't remove the hard links in other sub directories

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf foo
```

`rm` - remove files or directories.

- `-f` ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt.
- `-r` remove directories and their contents recursively.

Comment: yes but this doesn't remove the hard linked file that are in other sub directories right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all the files that are hard linked to any of the files found via descending `foo`, with GNU tools, you could do:

```
dir=foo
mountpoint=$(df --output=target -- "$dir" | tail -n +2)

awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
  ARGIND == 1 {inum[$0]; next}
  {i=$0; getline}
  i in inum
 ' <(find -- "$dir" -xdev ! -type d -links +1 -printf '%i\0') \
   <(find -- "$mountpoint" -xdev ! -type d -printf '%i\0%p\0') |
  xargs -r0 rm -f

rm -rf -- "$dir"
```

That assumes GNU `df`, GNU `awk`, GNU `find` and a shell like the GNU shell (`bash`) that supports process substitution (`<(...)`).

That also assumes `$dir` doesn't start with `-` or doesn't happen to be a `find` predicate (like `!`, `(`...).

Above we look for files on the whole file system `$dir` belongs to. You can replace `$mountpoint` with just the parent directory of `$dir` (`.` in this case) or the other *subdirs* (`123 ABC def` here) if you know all the hardlinks are only in there.

In the code above, we record the inode numbers of all the non-directory files with a link count greater  than 1 that are found via descending `$dir`. And look for those inode numbers in the whole file system (at least sections of it that are not masked by other file systems and that you have permissions to traverse). inode numbers are only unique per-filesystem, so we use `-xdev` to make sure we only scan the one file system `$dir` is found on.

Comment: thank you for this answer but i don't think its this complicated because its an assignment which suppose to be like one or two line commands